# How to install gdal with 'pipenv install' using CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS

Tags: python, gdal, pipenv

If I mention "gdal = '2.2.3'" in the Pipfile and launch the instruction `pipenv install`, the install fails.

If I launch the instruction `CFLAGS="-I /usr/include/gdal" CXXFLAGS="-I /usr/include/gdal" pipenv install GDAL==2.2.3` the install succeed.

Is there a way to add the options '`CFLAGS="-I /usr/include/gdal" CXXFLAGS="-I /usr/include/gdal"`' into the Pipfile so that they are taken in consideration when launching 'pipenv install'?

Answer (score 1):

Potential solution: create a `.env` file defining the `CFLAGS` etc environment variables in your project directory.

Pipenv automatically reads this file if it exists and instantiates any environment variables, when the venv is activated.

Source: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env

Comment: It seems that .env is used only when you use `pipenv shell` or `pipenv run`, but not on `pipenv install`.